# phpbb - Allow guests to view topics but NOT posts

Tags: php, forums, phpbb3

I would like to allow guests to view the forum topics but not view the posts however if i provide read access they can read both.

Is there a way i can stop them viewing the posts?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you post some code so we can see how your forum is implemented, it's pretty impossible to suggest good ways of limiting permissions.

Comment: Apologies. i did wonder if this was a simple admin CP edit or do i have to roll my own permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have PHPBB3 -

- Log into your Admin Panel
- Select the Users and Groups tab
- Under groups, on the left, select Group Forum Permissions
- Select "GUEST"
- If you want to apply this to all forums, click the check box that says "select all"
- Assign the "Read Only" Permission to each forum